# Html button displayed through Javascript not functional

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have a JavaScript function that displays or hides a popup window when called, depending on the visibility of the window.  A previous version of this function worked great.  That is, the close button caused the window to disappear as it should.  However, since adding some code to the function, the close button no longer works.  Below are the previous and current versions of the function, the 'overlay' div which it manipulates, and the CSS for the div.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I can't figure out which of my changes has caused the issue, nor how to fix it.

Previous (working) function:

```
<script>
function overlay(descrip, name) {
    var descripBox = "<div><h3>"+name+"</h3><p>"+ descrip +"</p></br><input type='button' onclick='overlay()' value='Close'></input></div>";
    var el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el.innerHTML = descripBox;
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
</script>
```

Current (not working) function:

```
<script>
function overlay(descrip, name, req) {
    if(req != ''){
        var obj = new Array();
        obj = req.split("|");
        var reqHtml = "Requirements:</br><ul>";
        for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
        {
            reqHtml += "<li>"+obj[i]+"</li>";
        }
        reqHtml+= "</ul></br>";
    }
    else
        var reqHtml = '';
    var descripBox = "<div><h3>"+name+"</h3><p>"+ descrip +"</p></br>"+
        reqHtml +"<center><input type='button' onclick='overlay()' value='Close'></input></center></div>";
    var el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el.innerHTML = descripBox;
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
</script>
```

Overlay div:

```
<div id="overlay">
     <div>
          </br>
          <input type="button" onclick="overlay()" value="Close"></input>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#overlay {
     visibility: hidden;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     top: 500px;        
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     z-index: 1000;
}

#overlay div {
     width:300px;
     margin: 100px auto;
     background-color: #ebebeb;
     border:2px solid #c7c7c7;
     padding:15px;   
}
```

Comment: If you write valid HTML, that would sure make it more likely to work ?

Comment: Oops- bit of a beginner here.  Fixing the tags didn't help, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your code seems very strange.

```
    if(req != ''){
        var obj = new Array();
        obj = req.split("|");
        var reqHtml = "Requirements:</br><ul>";
        for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
        {
            reqHtml += "<li>"+obj[i]+"</li>";
        }
        reqHtml+= "</ul></br>";
    }
```

That part **will be called** because you are calling your function with no parameters :

```
 onclick="overlay()"
```

That makes req being undefined. But in Javascript, undefined equals to empty string (your '') and equals to 0 or false. Unless you use a "!==" which means strictly not equal, meaning that you need an empty string.

Then, this :

```
   else
        var reqHtml = '';
```

is bad. I'm not sure if you forgot the brackets or what, but **always** put the brackets around a if/else, unless you want to put it all on a line. This is to avoid errors if you want to add an instruction between the two lines. Also, you var here makes the reqHTML variable in the "else" scope, and so not accessible out of it.

That means you should declare it at the beginning of the function, making your code look like this :

```
var reqHtml = '';
if(req != ''){
        var obj = new Array();
        obj = req.split("|");
        var reqHtml = "Requirements:</br><ul>";
        for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
        {
            reqHtml += "<li>"+obj[i]+"</li>";
        }
        reqHtml+= "</ul></br>";
}
var descripBox = "<div><h3>"+name+"</h3><p>"+ descrip +"</p></br>"+
        reqHtml +"<center><input type='button' onclick='overlay()' value='Close'></input></center></div>";
var el = document.getElementById("overlay");
```

Then, I think detecting the css to know what to do is a bad way of thinking because it could be undefined for exemple. You would be better creating a variable "boxVisibility" to describe it (or even a class box, so you can manage more stuff intelligently).

Finally, all your function parameters are undefined anyway. That means you should keep them global or read them somewhere at the beginning of your function. Here is an exemple that should work :

```
var descrip = "Test desc";
var name = "Test name";
var req = "test req";
var boxVisibility = true;

function updateBox() {
    var reqHtml = '';
    if(req != ''){
            var obj = new Array();
            obj = req.split("|");
            var reqHtml = "Requirements:</br><ul>";
            for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
            {
                reqHtml += "<li>"+obj[i]+"</li>";
            }
            reqHtml+= "</ul></br>";
        }
        var descripBox = "<div><h3>"+name+"</h3><p>"+ descrip +"</p></br>"+
            reqHtml +"<center><input type='button' onclick='overlay()' value='Close'></input></center></div>";
        var el = document.getElementById("overlay");
        el.style.visibility = (boxVisibility) ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
function overlay() {
    boxVisibility = !boxVisibility; // Invert the box visibility variable
    updateBox(); // Update box display
}
```

Then you should change desc, name and req depending on what you want to do in your application.